# How to make a special number phone call in Android ending with #

Tags: android, button, phone-call

I'm a new android application programmer.

I created a button in my application that calls a number ie. `*144#` but it keep ignoring the # and dialing *144 only.

How do i ensure it calls the whole number?

Code Snippet:

```
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:*144#"));
startActivity(callIntent);`
```

Answer (score 0):

Url encode it.

```
String number = "tel:*144%23";
callIntent.setData(Uri.parse(asd));
```

Or if you need a more general approach (like if you numbers change...) - encode the data part of the URI with a URLEncoder.

```
String number = "tel:"+ URLEncoder.encode("*144#");
....
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple use Uri encode :

```
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:"+ Uri.encode("*144#")));
startActivity(callIntent);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
  Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse("tel:*144" + Uri.encode("#")));
  startActivity(callIntent);
```

it worked for me.

Answer (score -2):

`#` is a special character that sends command to operator. I don't think that you can actually call any number ending with `#`.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: I said this request is impossible. so there is not a real answer for this question